# How to extract Map values from set

Tags: java

My Map has below key = value pair, now how to get the GCO value from the set {} ?

```
MAP : {containerIdentifier={ID=null, dto=null, GCO=123, version=1}, containerEditable=true}
```

code :

```
        for (Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet())
System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() +", Value = " + entry.getValue());
```

Output :

```
Key = containerIdentifier, Value = {ID =null, dto=null, GCO=123, version=1}
Key = containerEditable, Value = true
```

how to get the only GCO 123 from value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check when the value of the original `Map` is also a `Map`. Then you can cast it to a `Map` and lookup the value of a specific key in that inner `Map`:

```
for (Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue() instanceof Map) {
        Map innermap = (Map) entry.getValue();
        System.out.println(innermap.get("GCO"));
    }
}
```

This is assuming the value of the original `Map` is not always a `Map` (and considering the second entry in your sample `Map`, whose value is a `Boolean`, that assumption is correct).

Answer (score 2):

You could use java steam api.

```
map.values().stream()
            .flatMap(innerMaps -> innerMaps.entrySet().stream())
            .filter(entry-> "GCO".equals(entry.getKey()))
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .findAny().orElse("not found")
```